# https ubuntu lamp

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2, lamp

Настроил сервер LAMP (ubuntu) в соответствии с [ЭТОЙ](https://losst.ru/ustanovka-lamp-ubuntu-16-04) инструкцией, добавил виртуальный хост `test.site`, все работает, и если зайти по адресу `http://test.site`, будет показана страница, лежащая в `/var/www/test.site/public_html/`, но если зайти по адресу `httpS://test.site` (букву S специально выделил), то будет показана страница, лежащая в папке `/var/www/html`

Как исправить такое поведение apache и сделать так, чтобы при входе по адресу `https://test.site` показывалась страница, лежащая в `/var/www/test.site/public_html/`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/28041/how-do-i-make-apache-web-server-listen-on-two-different-ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у Вас не сконфигурирован хост test.site для работы по SSL.

1. Генерируем сертификаты для хоста.
2. Редактируем конфигурационный файл test.site

Пример конфигурации

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName test.site
                ServerAlias www.test.site
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                DocumentRoot /var/www/test.site/public_html
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/test.site.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/test.site.key
        </VirtualHost> </IfModule>
```